# hello StartupCommand PureMVC cpp with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, puremvc

What would be the simplest example of `CMakeLists.txt`, `main.cpp` and `PureMVC sources` to display "Hello Startup" from execute() Startup SimpleCommand?

PureMVC sources are [here](https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-cpp-multicore-framework)

Ideally solution could be a link to github project.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile corresponding dll and lib (Debug or Release [static|shared]), include PureMVC files. Maybe you can derive a facade from PureMVC::Patterns::Facade, override essential virtual functions. Because it's different between C++ and Java-like programming languages, overrided initializeController() won't be called in base class's constructor!
Here is a derive example:

```
class ApplicationFacade
    : public virtual IFacade
    , public Facade
{
    friend class Facade;
public:
    static const string STARTUP;
    static const string EXIT;
protected:
    ApplicationFacade(void)
        : Facade(this, "ApplicationFacade")
    {
        initializeController();
    }

public:
    static ApplicationFacade& getInstance(void)
    {
        if (Facade::hasCore("ApplicationFacade"))
            return *(dynamic_cast<ApplicationFacade*>(&Facade::getInstance("ApplicationFacade")));
        return *(new ApplicationFacade());
    }

protected:
    virtual void initializeNotifier(string const& key)
    {
        Facade::initializeNotifier(key);
    }
    virtual void initializeFacade()
    {
        Facade::initializeFacade();
    }

    virtual void initializeController(void)
    {
        Facade::initializeController();
        StartupCommand* startupCommand = new StartupCommand();
        registerCommand(STARTUP, startupCommand);
        ExitCommand* exitCommand = new ExitCommand();
        registerCommand(EXIT, exitCommand);
    }

    ~ApplicationFacade()
    {
    }
};
const string ApplicationFacade::STARTUP = "startup";
const string ApplicationFacade::EXIT = "exit";
```

StartupCommand and ExitCommand are derived from PureMVC::Patterns::SimpleCommand
Then in main.cpp you can start the program by:

```
ApplicationFacade& facade = ApplicationFacade::getInstance();
facade.sendNotification(ApplicationFacade::STARTUP);
```

And exit:

```
facade.sendNotification(ApplicationFacade::EXIT);
```